# Ext4 fast_commit feature

Tags: filesystems, ext4

Since 5.10 kernel there is a new feature called ***fast_commit***. In arch wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ext4 you can read that it can be enabled in existing filesystem with:

`tune2fs -O fast_commit /dev/drivepartition`

but in https://lwn.net/Articles/842385/ there is:

> Fast commits are activated at filesystem creation time, so users will
> have to recreate their filesystems to use this feature.

So is `tune2fs -O fast_commit` truly enable this feature in existing filesystem ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`tune2fs -O fast_commit` is supported since e2fsprogs 1.46.0, which was released [two weeks after the LWN article was published](https://lwn.net/Articles/844961/). So the article was correct at the time of publication, and the Arch wiki is correct now.

`tune2fs -O fast_commit` doesn’t just set the corresponding flag, it creates all the required data structures; the required functions were [added in late January 2021](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/commit/?id=3cc4f867441b5e7172826876a39d3957c8da745d), and [`tune2fs` was then updated to use them](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/commit/?id=06def17e2f20135771f520cc88324ca8a3f1f3cb). You can run it even on a mounted system, and check with `dumpe2fs` that the feature was indeed enabled (look for “Fast commit length” and check that it’s non-zero).

Comment: Thank you. Seems it works: `Fast commit length:       256`